# How to undo serial upvote?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I helped an user, and *I think* he upvoted my last 5 answers as *gratitude*, how do I notify a moderator to undo his votes?

Comment: As written in the the answer, nothing to do for you, but you could ping the user who did that let him/her know that this behaviour isn't helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to do anything.  There is a serial voting reversal script that runs every day.  If after 24 hours the votes are still not gone then you can either use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) page to report that you think you were serial up voted and ask them to take a look or you can just carry on as nothing happened.

Comment: Realistically, if the script misses it, it's probably not worth bothering SE staff members to manually invalidate the votes. I wouldn't worry about it, unless this becomes a persistent problem where someone is trying to troll you.

Comment: @BradLarson Same here.  I had this about a month or 2 ago and the script didn't reverse so I just went on with my life.